# Downgrading to iOS 9.3.5 After apple stopped signing

Tags: ios

I need to test upgrade from iOS 9.3.5 to iOS 10. Since apple stopped signing iOS 9 [Link](http://www.redmondpie.com/ios-9.3.5-and-ios-10.0.1-are-no-longer-being-signed-by-apple-heres-what-that-means/)

Does it mean that now, there is no other way to downgrade device iOS 9.3.5 or is there any other way to test update of the application?

Thank you very much for your help. 
Best,

Matti

Comment: What do you mean by "test update of the application"? Nothing is done to the **app** when the **os** is updated. So, what do you want to test?

Comment: Hello FreeNickname, we use fingerprint or gestures to allow users access their account. However, when users update from iOS 9 to iOS 10, they need to register again - by registration I mean adding one time key and pre-generated key. The problem is that it is the only case when we were able to simulate it, but we are out of devices for iOS 9.